# Microsoft ILogger not working inside Controller if Host started inside unit test library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, nlog, serilog

Things to clarify first is that I use *NLog/Serilog/etc* for neat configuration, across all applications I only use *Microsoft.** namespce logging interfaces.

Here is example of my Site startup class, which just reference host builder form real app, so it is complete integration friendly class which I can use in `SetUp` and `TearDown` in *NUnit*:

```
public sealed class Site
{
    private IHost _host;
    public readonly string BaseAddress;

    public Site(string baseAddress)
    {
        BaseAddress = baseAddress;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        if (_host != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already started.");

        var cfgBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var args = string.Format("--urls {0}", BaseAddress);
        cfgBuilder.AddCommandLine(args.Split(' ', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        cfgBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        cfgBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(5000);
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();
            _host = Performance.Program.CreateHostBuilder(cfgBuilder.Build()).UseSerilog(Log.Logger).Build();
            await _host.StartAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        if (_host == null)
            return;
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(5000);
            await _host.StopAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

My *appsettings.*.json* pretty much default:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

But here is the problem. Microsoft `ILogger` work inside `IHostedService` or `Startup` instances, **BUT** it stop working entirely in any controller/middleware:

```
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> _logger;

    public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("error")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnError()
    {
        _logger.LogError("This one won't ever show up in test library except if you stop using serilog/nlog/whatever.");
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

If I start my app normally through `Program.cs` rather than from *TestExplorer* - everything fine and logging. So here is table of error replication with same configuration on different loggers I used:

```
Framework        |NUnit.Startup |NUnit.Controller |Program.Startup |Program.Controller
___________________________________________________________________________________
NLog             |good          |bad              |good            |good
Serilog          |good          |bad              |good            |good
Microsoft logger |good          |good             |good            |good
```

So, as you see, **Microsoft logger works everywhere** and project is pretty much clean default generation in *VS*. I tried completely clearing providers, various combination of extension, etc. What am I missing?

Comment: This will be a hard one to answer. Should we fix for both libraries? Is the answer valid if only one is answered? Please choose one library - this now too broad in my opinion.

Comment: (for both libraries the specific setup seems to be missing in the question)

Comment: Break in the debugger inside your action method and examine `ILogger` and its linked objects. Compare with the instance in startup.

Comment: I will try write my own logger factory and come back with difference.

Comment: After some debugging, I found out that Console.WriteLine not working.....damn, must be some redirection problem. If I write to file it WORKS!!! If I write to some concurrent collection it works! But not working if I write to console.....hell

Comment: @Julian, you should probably log to console through background thread, not directly. I mean this - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/93be7531b634fd08001c2062d0f61a2db129322f/src/NLog/Targets/ColoredConsoleSystemPrinter.cs#L99 should be like this - https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/2d2f31968229eddb57b6ba3d34696ef366a6c71b/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/Internal/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs I think this can be done just by  enabling async enqueue of log event.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this some strange behavior of..... `Console`+ `IHost` and thread in which its running! Yes, you didn't misread. Things happens and for some reason `Console` will not work in thread of your `IHost` class after it starts - it will be back once you call `StopAsync` though. It will be nice if someone would explain this behavior further, I don't have decompiler at the moment in machine.

Solution is just to enable background processing of your logs, so they will be logged to `Console` but in some other thread.

For example in *Serilog*:

```
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Async(a=>
            {
                a.Console();
            })
            .CreateLogger();
```

In *NLog* you could use their [async wrapper](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target), but I didn't tested that.

Microsoft probably knew this behavior and their `logging.AddConsole()` extension works through [background process](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/2d2f31968229eddb57b6ba3d34696ef366a6c71b/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/Internal/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs), so this is the reason why their logger worked and others didn't.